# Setting up Log Based alerts in StackDriver across multiple projects in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver

We have a project in Google Cloud called 'A' where we ship our application logs to Stackdriver and have a few Log Based alerts configured. Now we have another project in Google Cloud namely B. Is there a way we can set up Log based alerts in Project B which can access logs from Project A?

Asking this question mainly because we run into situation where we have exhausted quota for settings up alerts in Stackdriver in Project A

Answer (score 0):

In order to get logs based metrics for Project A into project B, you'd have to copy the logs, which would be an inefficient way to solve your problem.  We do have some changes to Stackdriver Accounts planned in the future which would resolve this issue but it sounds like the root of the problem is the set of alerting policies in use (will follow up offline to see how we can help with that).